# Developing a Maven Plugin - consequence of upgrading `maven-core` version?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

When developing Maven plugins, do the versions of Maven framework dependencies like `maven-core` have any special consequences?

I'm new to developing Maven plugins. I recently submitted a GitHub pull request (https://github.com/talios/googleformatter-maven-plugin/pull/16) which upgrades the version of `maven-core`. The maintainer reasonably asked if that would have consequences like forcing all plugin developers or plugin users to upgrade their Maven versions. Anecdotally I don't think that's the case (see the PR), but I'm not sure what other consequences might happen.